# Son necesarios los prefijos en css?

Tags: html, css, css3, web, navegador-web

que tal? Queria hacer una pregunta de principiante.
Durante 2 años me ausente en el mundo del desarrollo web. Pero ahora que he vuelto, viendo algunos cursos o tutoriales de css, me di cuenta que nadie usa prefijos, para que ciertas propiedades sean visibles en todos los navegadores. Mi pregunta es: actualmente en 2020 es importante utilizar los prefijos en css. Y si si son necesarios, cuales serian algunos ejemplo en los que tenemos que utilizarlos?

Comment: Tu pregunta luce basada en opiniones por qué existirán quienes te digan que es necesario por compatibilidad y otros como yo quienes te diremos que no, basate mejor en caniuse.com ahí comprueba el soporte a algunas características de css

Comment: Esta pregunta quedará mejor en [chat]

Comment: Como dice @BetaM, es cuestión de opiniones, depende del cliente para quien trabajes, ya que los visitantes de las páginas no suelen informar de fallos, en mi caso yo no los usaba tanto, pero esto hacía que de repente más de un cliente me preguntara porqué en android, en algún safary o PC con navegadores descontinados (por razones ajenas a ellos) se miraba de tal forma, y pues como todo responsable, me tocaba agregar algunos prefijos, al final opté por instalar un prefixer en emmet. Es irónico que para el cliente, si en su navegador viejo no ve bien su página, el maquetador es el culpable.

Answer (score 1):

Tu pregunta está más orientada a opiniones pero trataré de ser objetivo:

Los prefijos se utilizan en propiedades que están en fase experimental o que aún no se han convertido en estándar.

Los prefijos son simplemente prefijos que se añaden al inicio de una propiedad para que sea aplicada a un navegador específico:

```
-prefix-property: value
```

Todo dependerá de cuánto estás dispuesto a sacrificar para añadir esa propiedad específica a la mayor cantidad de usuarios posible.

¿A qué se tiende cuando me refiero a sacrificar?

- Mayor cantidad de bytes por código por el uso de prefijos
- Uso de propiedades en fase experimental que pueden ser excluidas en el futuro

Te recomiendo siempre utilizar propiedades que no necesiten de prefijos para verse en todos los navegadores puesto que si se necesitan prefijos es porque efectivamente no es estándar, no tiene una base sólida y hay dudas respecto a esa propiedad que te puede obligar a eliminarla en el futuro o incluso romper tu código o la idea que tenías del diseño que deseabas crear.